# Facebook app invite not worked with real friend

Tags: ios, facebook, invite

I m working on one app which is not live, And app has facebook app invite feature.

My problem is that app invite is only work when users are fb test use, when i tried this with real users invite is not working so how can i test fb app invite on real user when my app is not live.

Comment: You can refer answer below to know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the accounts as Test Users. When the app goes live, only then other users can be used to send invite.

More details on creating test users here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users

Answer (score 0):

Add all those users as test users in your app on facebook & share your app with them. You can test your functionality once you have them added in facebook dashboard as test users, & this functionality will work for real users once your app is live.